# Copper shale in the Harz Mountains (Germany)

Tags: geology

I wanted to ask if you have any suitable literature on copper slate (especially about the genesis) in the Harz Mountains. I was generally interested in how this copper shale differs from other copper shales.

Comment: Hi if you are able to read in german, I would recomend you: Historischer Bergbau im Harz by Wilfried Liessmann

Comment: [Formation Conditions of Copper-Sandstone and Copper-Shale Deposits](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-70902-9_34), [A New Look at the Geology of the Zambian Copper belt](https://eprints.utas.edu.au/755/0), [Polymetallic Mineralization at the Browns Deposit, Rum Jungle Mineral Field, Northern Territory, Australia](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273226096_Polymetallic_Mineralization_at_the_Browns_Deposit_Rum_Jungle_Mineral_Field_Northern_Territory_Australia)